# Ubuntu 20.04 Copy file to folder with UI?

Tags: 20.04, copy

I need to copy a file from the desktop to a folder with the graphical user interface, not the command line.

When I drag and drop the system does nothing.

Is there a security issue? What is the process?

Comment: I trying to copy a png file on my desktop to a folder called Boat Ideas.

Comment: The target destination is: byron@bbp7550:/mnt/867ff8ab-bc46-4f1c-bc0f-ad0c485954c0/P7550-DATA/NAUTICAL/Boat/Boat Ideas$

Comment: This is an additional internal hard drive on a Dell laptop. It does not contain the OS.  The system will not copy to byron@bbp7550:~/Pictures$ either. The folder pictures is on the same drive as the OS. I'm speaking of using drag and drop like windows.

Comment: Both of the following worked in terminal: cp ~/Desktop/TEMP-TEST.png  ~/Pictures/ 

cp ~/Desktop/TEMP-TEST.png  /mnt/867ff8ab-bc46-4f1c-bc0f-ad0c485954c0/P7550-DATA/NAUTICAL/Boat/Boat-Ideas/

Comment: Can this be done with the graphical user interface?

Comment: Ok that rules out a few things. Using the GUI file manager, can you select files and copy with Ctrl+C and paste Ctrl+V? Also is this a new problem or have you never been able to drag and drop? If it's a new problem, what actions or changes closely correspond with the new problematic behavior?

Comment: I've never been able to copy/paste a file to another folder. I can Ctrl+C and Ctrl-V into a Word document. However, the Ctrl-V does not work inside a folder. The drop-down options  of Boat-Ideas has "Paste" grayed out too.

Comment: This is not normal behavior. We need to figure out what's different about your system from everyone else's that is causing this problem. Only after we've determined *why* this is happening can we figure out a solution. As another diagnostic, I suggest that you boot a liveUSB with Ubuntu and see if you can copy files when using a "clean" unaltered version of Ubuntu. If you don't have the problem in a live session, then the problem likely exists somewhere within your installed system. If you still have the problem, then the problem probably has to do with the file system of the volume itself.

Comment: Just FYI from what you've already tried, if details are accurate, we've ruled out a read-only file system, incompatible file system, or permissions issues. You should advise and add details if you have ever added software from anywhere except the software center, if you've added sources, changed desktop environments, made changes to configuration files, removed preinstalled software, or installed addons or extensions or other tools or tweaks to your UI that are not available as a stock configuration option -- even if you later attempted to reverse these actions

Comment: Nmath, thank you for your help.
A right click on a photo on a USB drive gives the options copy to and move to.  These options are not available on files that are on the Ubunto drives. 
1)My Dell laptop came pre-installed with Ubuntu. It has no other OS on it. The extra internal hard drive was installed by Dell, but not configured to Ubuntu.   I formatted it to use for data storage. The main drive is for OS and applications.
2) Installed wine and MS Office 2007.  
Continued on next comment...

Comment: 3) Installed Canon scanner drivers for my ImageCLASS MF232w printer.  This printer is by USB connection and does not scan, but can print.
4) Installed HP scanner drivers for my LaserJet Pro MFP M125nw.  This is by wifi connection and does not scan, but can print.
5) Installed FoxFire
6) Installed DuckDuckGo
7) Installed GIMP 2.0
 
It probably will take a few days to figure out liveUSB with Ubuntu to do the test.

Comment: Solution: 
Access your "Desktop" folder from "Home". 
Copy/cut from there and paste to any folder. 
Note: Copying from your desktop directly may not work except you change the permission of the Desktop folder from "Home". I was working directly from the desktop and it failed. When I accessed desktop through home, it worked.